# How to compare 2 gridviews which bind to a same table - C#?

Tags: c#, comparison, grid

How to compare 2 gridviews which bind to a same table in C#?

1. For example if the table name is employees, i need to bind to two grids  - Grid1 and Grid2.
2. The Employees tables reside in two different Access databases.

   Grid1- Connects to Database1 - Binds Employee table and
   Grid2- Connects to Database2 - Binds Employee table
3. If i have 3 rows in Grid1 and if i have 2 rows in Grid2, then 3rd row of  Grid1- Connects to Database1 - Binds Employee should be shown in red color and when i click an update button outside the grid, the 3rd row should be updated in Grid2.

Comparing and Syncing

Please give some help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you just say?? that made very little sense.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Sorry, Please read the question again as i have edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: I was only kidding. Check out my answer below.

Comment: Can't you replicate the data from one database to another? Don't you want both of them to be equivalent?

Comment: Yes i can replicate but before that if the rows are equal and if the column values are different then i need to show that column(s) alone in red colour and then i can overwrite on some update button click. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some sort of a key to know that a row in grid1 *should* equal a row in grid 2?

Answer (score 0):

Do this on buttonclick. I'm not sure i understand your question fully but just bind them then compare them.

```
If gridview1.rows.count > gridview2.rows.count then

 GridView1.Rows(GridView1.Rows.Count - 1).backcolor = red

end if
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, but if i have 3 rows in both the grids & if the data in any row is different from another grid's row(s), then at that time i need to show that particular column in red background

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compare datatables? Get index of rows which are different in a collection. Then iterate through each row of gridview and set the background color as Eric has suggested.